# NodeJS Routes only work on localhost else theyre 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, httprequest

I'm trying to create a simple website with Node.js! I installed node.js on the server,i set up DNS and started my server. On a button click a  POST HTTP request "/buildRequest" should be sent to the server. Inside this route, an external function should be called that returns an Object containing an
ErrorMessage(an Object like error:"this is an error") or an path(string) to a file.It works perfectly fine if I go on the page via localhost:8888(port i'm using). The route will get called. But if i go on the website with the DNS name and click on the button the page says :
 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var dbFunc = require("./dbFunctions.js");
var util = require('util');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 8888;
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;
//allow to use body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//allow to use static files
app.use(express.static("public"));
//listen to smth
app.post('/buildRequest', function (req, res) {
        //buildrequest call was succ
        var main = dbFunc.main(req.body.dbParameter, function (data) {
            var result = data;
                res.send(result);
        });
});
//start server
app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on port" + port);
```

My client side js function that get triggerd when clicking a specific button :

```
function callServerSideScript(dbParameter) {
    //do check here if a value is missing
   db = document.getElementById(dbParameter).value;
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    httpRequest.open('POST', '/buildRequest')
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.send("dbParameter=" + db);
    httpRequest.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
       try {
        //if try is successfull response is an object. Return the object as string(error message)
        var test = JSON.parse(this.response);
        alert(this.response);
       } catch (error) {
        //is not an object,means its a string = download
        window.open("/download");
       }  
      } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
      }
    };

    httpRequest.onerror = function () {
      // There was a connection error of some sort
    };
  }
```

Why does the route work with localhost on the server but not "remote" when accessing the website outside the server?

EDIT :
My folder structure looks like this :
main.js containing client side functions(like doing the HTTP request)

```
.
+--public
|   + index.html
|   + <someother html files>
|   + main.js
|
+-- server.js
|
|
+-- dbFunctions.js
```

Greetings

Comment: You have `app.use(express.static("public"))` in your express server. When you run the app locally, what does your folder structure look like? Do you have a `public` directory next to your server with the `.html` and `.js` files to be served to your client? Your `index.html` file that express serves when browsing the site should be at the root of the `public` directory on the server, and any script references should be relative to that path.

Comment: @Josh Ah sorry! i added the folder structure to the main post. But im a bit confused.. When doing the POST Http request i dont actually want to send another html to the client. When doing the POST Http request(clicking that html button) i just want to run a server side function and return a value based on diverse things that get calculated in my dbFunctions.js(which works perfectly fine). When the route sends something back to the client(response) i want to stay on the same html as before.Also accessing the html files is no problem outside the server. Just the POST http request doesnt work.

Comment: I think you just need to move `app.post` before you call `app.use`, or define an express router `const router = express.Router()`, then setup your routes like `router.post('/buildRequest', (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); }` and do `app.use('/buildRequest', router)`

Comment: Still the same error for me.In "httpRequest.onload = function() {} My status is 404

Comment: Open the developer tools for your browser and look in the network tab. Refresh the page and watch for the XHR call in the network tab to your server. What URL is the request going to?

Comment: Also, separate from the above--I would install something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and try to send the POST request manually to `localhost:888/buildRequest`. This will allow you to test your POST route is accepting the request and responding as expected--separate from the client. Once you've established that you can hit the POST route in Postman, you can isolate any problems with the client formatting or sending the request to the server incorrectly versus something on the server stopping the request from ever getting to your code in the first place.

Comment: @Josh Just checked the request in the network tab. The request going to my Page xxxx.net/buildRequest or <ip>/buildRequest. Method is POST,Source is xhr and type is html. Is it because the Client/Page "asking" for a buildRequest file/ html?

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Chrome dev tools, looking at a POST request from one of my sites, the Type column lists `xhr`. I don't see `html` anywhere, but it may say `html` because you're using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Maybe try using `Content-Type: application/json` and putting the JSON data into the body of the POST request. That is actually what you expecting in the route since you're looking at `req.body` for your data. You may also want to add the `bodyParser` npm package for express if you haven't already done so.